# Назначение события по клику на строку меню

Tags: css, меню

Вот моё меню в мобильной/планшетной версии сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как поставил плагин вордпресс, при клике на одну из строк меню (например обувь), оно развернётся(видно на картинке), но это происходит если кликнуть правее самого слова. А если кликать именно по слову, то меню сворачивается всё время. 
Как настроить в css чтобы меню разворачивалось при клике на любом месте строки?

Comment: Для начала нужно посмотреть живой пример, чтобы понять что именно не так.

Comment: ali-coupons.net

Answer (score 1):

На вашей странице два экземпляра меню - `<div id="primary-nav">` и  `<nav id="mobile-menu">`. В HTML-исходнике страницы они выглядят похоже, но панель отладки показывает, что проблемный пункт меню оказывается завернут в две ссылки сразу:

```
<a href="#" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" class="slicknav_item slicknav_row" style="">
  <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Категория купонов</a>
  <span class="slicknav_arrow">▼</span>
</a>
```

Если оставить только одну ссылку, то список подпунктов начинает разворачиваться как надо.

```
<a href="#" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" class="slicknav_item slicknav_row">
  Категория купонов
  <span class="slicknav_arrow">▼</span>
</a>
```

Для начала попробуйте оставить этот пункт мобильного меню совсем без ссылки. Если какой-то из ваших скриптов сам добавит недостающую ссылку, то всё заработает. Если не добавит, то надо покопаться в скриптах и внимательно последить за их руками.

Comment: если бы я ещё понимал где это изменить, в каком файле. Просто там несколько php файлов, где конкретно - нет таких строк. Вы наверно в консоли браузера посмотрели ситуацию, не подскажите где мне изменить написанное вами выше?

Comment: @Sven Вижу три пути: 1) найти php-файл, который создаёт HTML-код мобильного меню, и изменить его так, чтобы заголовки выпадающих подменю не заворачивались в ссылку; 2) найти скрипт, который заворачивает эти заголовки в дополнительную ссылку и научить его одновременно удалять ссылку, добавленную вордпрессом; 3) написать скрипт, который будет удалять лишние ссылки из меню. В любом случае придется  и в коде копаться, и гуглить.